# PhpStorm never stops at breakpoints with Xdebug

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug, breakpoints

I try to config PhpStorm to work with Xdebug on remote server. With Xdebug hosted on localhost with WAMP it's worked.

I've used Putty to tunnel port 9000 from my remote server, telnetting is working, I get the black screen.

Xdebug configuration is as follow:

```
zend_extension = /usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_host="127.0.0.1"
xdebug.remote_autostart =1
xdebug.remote_enable =1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

Whenever I press debug on PhpStorm I it stucks on "connecting to localhost:3308" for some reason.

I use ‪Xdebug helper‬ 1.6.1 in Chrome 63. On my server I use Xdebug 2.6 with PHP Version 7.1.10. I use PhpStorm 2017.3.1.

EDIT 1:
it seems that the log is not opened at the server side here is the log:

```
Log opened at 2017-12-26 11:11:31
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:9009.
W: Creating socket for '127.0.0.1:9009', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
E: Could not connect to client. :-(
Log closed at 2017-12-26 11:11:31

Log opened at 2017-12-26 11:11:31
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:9009.
W: Creating socket for '127.0.0.1:9009', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
E: Could not connect to client. :-(
Log closed at 2017-12-26 11:11:31

Log opened at 2017-12-26 11:11:31
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:9009.
W: Creating socket for '127.0.0.1:9009', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
E: Could not connect to client. :-(
Log closed at 2017-12-26 11:11:31

Log opened at 2017-12-26 11:11:31
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:9009.
W: Creating socket for '127.0.0.1:9009', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
E: Could not connect to client. :-(
Log closed at 2017-12-26 11:11:31

Log opened at 2017-12-26 11:11:31
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:9009.
W: Creating socket for '127.0.0.1:9009', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
E: Could not connect to client. :-(
Log closed at 2017-12-26 11:11:31
```

telnetting locally to port 9009 is refused.

Does anyone knows why it doesn't work?

Comment: 1) Better stick to stable 2.5.5 version of xdebug -- 2.6 is still in alpha stage -- no need to risk, especially if you are not using PHP 7.2 2) What web server do you run on your server? How do you run PHP there? Is that php-fpm? if so -- do as suggested and change xdebug port to be 9001 (on the remote server) -- 9000 may be already used by php-pfm; 3) What xdebug log has to say? 4) *"it stucks on "connecting to localhost:3308""* Check your Run/Debug Configuration in PhpStorm -- they remember the URL.

Comment: Here are 2 more gotchas i could add go @LazyOne's list : 1) chmod 777 to `/whererver/is/xdebug.log` and 2) minimize your php window and see if there is no window there asking you to a) select which process you want to debug and b) match a uri to a physical file  (PhpStorm does that, hide critical prompts)

Comment: @lazyone
1)that what the formal site of xdebug send me to.
2)nginx. PHP-FPM. changed to port 9009. Thanks
3)attached in edit 1
4)can you link me to the instructions?

Comment: @ YvesLeBorg 
1)done!
2)I haven't seen one.
b)what do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

Change port to 9009 and do not forget to chane this setting in PhpStorm

Comment: change it as you said, see edit 1. no success so far.